# Photos consistently underexposed (despite setting iso, shutter speed and aperture)

Tags: exposure

My Nikon D700 is suddenly really dark and underexposed, even when shooting indoors with all the lights on so it's really bright. For example, at ISO 400, 1/80, f/2.8 on a 24-70, or ISO 400, 1/125, f/1.8 with a prime lens, it's pretty much black. I need to set the ISO to at least 2000 to be anywhere near correctly exposed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my ISO go below 6400 when I shoot indoors?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-wont-my-iso-go-below-6400-when-i-shoot-indoors)

Comment: 'All the lights on' is _not_ very bright compared to sunlight; the human eye makes you think so, but it is still a thousand times darker. Try outside with sunshine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my camera metering indoor scenes as darker than I expect, forcing me to use a high ISO?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48668/why-is-my-camera-metering-indoor-scenes-as-darker-than-i-expect-forcing-me-to-u)

Comment: With those settings were you getting an exposed shot inside prior? Otherwise I agree wuth @Aganju

Comment: I would suggest that you upload some sample images in some "standarized" conditions, for example in sunlight, indoors with light comming into the room. Shoot them at low resolution and upload them in a way the original exif stays.

Answer (score 1):

Have you by any chance recently turned off *Auto ISO*? Have you recently used  negative amounts of *Exposure Compensation*? These and several other possible issue that could result in underexposed photos are covered in the questions linked below.

[Nikon d5100 producing extremely underexposed images](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59811/nikon-d5100-producing-extremely-underexposed-images)
[Why am I getting dark black photos in P, S, and A mode on Nikon D5200?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60229/why-am-i-getting-dark-black-photos-in-p-s-and-a-mode-on-nikon-d5200)
[Why is my Nikon lens suddenly extremely dark?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14988/why-is-my-nikon-lens-suddenly-extremely-dark)
[My photos are way too dark, must use 6000+ ISO inside](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/74974/my-photos-are-way-too-dark-must-use-6000-iso-inside)
[Wondering if my Nikon lens is broken](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59355/wondering-if-my-nikon-lens-is-broken)
[Nikon D5200 overexposed shots in "auto" modes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72413/nikon-d5200-overexposed-shots-in-auto-modes/72414#72414)

Comment: Neither.  It was working fine and suddenly super underexposed to the point you can't see anything. Possibly started doing it after a lens change,  but not 100% sure

Comment: I've also reset all settings back to default and it's the same

Comment: Please see the last link I just edited into the answer. If the lever is bent the other way it will cause underexposure, rather than over exposure. As you progress through the f-number settings the lens will stop down all the way several stops before you get to the f/22 setting.

Comment: I'm thinking it may be a bent aperture lever as u said.  I distinctly remember it didn't sound quite right (didn't even remember until I read ur link)  when I put the lens on last time and I'm sure when I had the lens on earlier today the aperture was at its smallest hole so probably f22 in the camera meaning it wasn't open before shutter press but I'm not 100% sure.  I'll check when I get in but I'm pretty sure that's what I've done. Hopefully I can fix with some pliers as I don't think it's a cheap fix :(

Answer (score 0):

**Only maybe one or more of:**

Unlock and turn lens somewhat and then reseat.
Do this several times.
(Processor can get confused if contacts bad).

Turn ON.
Battery out.
Leave several minutes.
Turn OFF.
Battery in
Turn on

Reset in Custom menu.

Reset in settings menu.

2 button reset - press and hold 2 green dot market buttons on top
(Qual on left, +/- on right.)

Master reset maybe>: Opinions vary. On the base at left rear by serial number the hole may house a reset button. On some Nikons it does. This may reset when held in with suitable pointed object (wooden toothpick or thin bamboo skewer usually safe). OT you may need to turn off, hold button in, turn on while holding button.
The latter is common on many systems. I tried it on a GPS unit and it wiped the program :-)  this is a VERY unusual response.

Turn ON
Remove battery.
Leave battery out for 24+ hours to some days.
Reinstall and try.
This is aimed at semi hard restart with discharge of capacitors. A well designed system will NOT need this and also not respond to it. It does work on some systems.

Phone Nikon.

Pray.

It's broken :-(.

**____________________________**

Just found this. As it is by Nikon USA and does NOT mention D700 having a hard rest it's not encouraging if that's what is needed.

[Nikon resetting](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17395/~/how-to-reset-a-d-slr-to-factory-default-settings)